# SFTP - How to Set Permission to Multiple Users

Tags: permissions

Hi I am New to Ubuntu and Don't know how to give permissions.

I have setup SFTP on WSL Ubuntu and i want to give permissions based on their role.

for example : I want to access One folder **/data/uploads**  to 10-15 users but some users have read Access , some users have read + write and Some users have Full access.

How to assign these type of permission to multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Use acl (access control language). The acl commands let you add permissions for any combination of users or groups to any files or directories. For example you can create a file, README, that Jane can edit but George can only read:

```
# create some file
touch README

# "normal" user and group permissions still work as before
sudo chown anyuser:anygroup README

# Let Jane read or write (no matter what her user group is)
setfacl u:jane:rw README
    
# Let the acolyte group read it
setfacl --modify g:acolyte:r

# Let George read it, even if he's not in the acolyte or the anygroup groups
setfacl --modify u:george:r README
```

Before you can run the setfacl command or any of the other acl commands, you have to install acl like this:

```
sudo apt install acl
```

Once you've install it, add "acl" to the options of any device in your /etc/fstab file that you want to use it with. for example, change:

```
/dev/sda1   /            ext3    noatime,errors=remount-ro      0 1
```

...to:

```
/dev/sda1   /            ext3    noatime,errors=remount-ro,acl      0 1
```

Note that the syntax for /etc/fstab is:

device-name | mount-point | file-system-type | options | dump | fsck-order

Just change the "options" part to get acl working.

You have to either reboot or remount the file system for the new acl features to work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier creating two groups `upread` and `upwrite` where the group `upwrite` also has read access? Then 10 to 15 users can be assigned to appropriate groups and user management becomes simplified.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the problem is that the file or directory can be owned by only one of those groups.

Comment: @EricMintz I am getting "Operation Not Supported" error.